# Object detection "consistency" when working with videos frame by frame

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

This is more of a general question than an issue and I hope I'm not being impolite asking it here. I swear I did my search but either my google-fu is lacking or the terms I'm using are completely of tracks or both.

How do you name the problem when doing object detection in a video where you detect some object on a frame but then on the next frame you don't detect it but then on the following one it gets detected again? I call it "flickering" but I am sure that is not the academic term.

And then, how do you solve this issue? After thinking about it, it seems to me that this problem is kind of related to object tracking, but then again this issue can happen when doing object detection for objects that are not moving.

Any hints and/or references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Short answer would be window and threshold. An elaborate answer would be, have a detection window. lets say, your window size is 5, and threshold is 3. Within the window, if the object occurs more than 3 times, then we say the object is present in all the frames in the window. Now the problem would be when scene changes. i.e. the object leaves the frame, even after that 1 or 2 frames will be classified to have the object. we need to find ways to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

I face similar problem while developing some object detection usecase - "flickering". No matter how good your detection is there will always be the flickering problem. In my case i solve the problem using either of the following methods:

1) If you are not computing any confidence value, then instead of deciding weather to show the detection in every frame you can take a history of frames and then decide weather to display or not. Select a threshold for number of frames and if detection is missing in all those previous frames for a specific location then only decide not to display else you can continue displaying.
for e.g: lets suppose you keep your number of frames threshold as 4, then you will be checking weather the detection is missing in all previous 4 frames then only skip displaying detection else you can display. This removes flickering to a very great extent.
*this case assumes that it is a real time video and not much changes occur in very consecutive frames.

2) Compute some confidence value associated to the object detection and check for that confidence value in consecutive frames for same location(i.e where the object was detected in previous frames). Even if the confidence of detection is slightly lower you can set threshold accordingly lower so that it still detects and hence flickering is removed.